# Kdb Q: Left join only on null rows

Tags: join, kdb

I want to perform a left join between two tables `t1` and `t2` on the column `id2` only if `id2` is null on the `t1` side.
As a qbie, I was wondering if it exists a better solution than mine below ?

````
t1: ([] id1:`AAA`BBB`CCC`DDD`EEE; id2:```02C``E25)
t2: ([] id1:`AAA`BBB`CCC`DDD`SSS; id2:`02A`02B`C2C`DD0`SPE)
````

---

Expected result:

```
([] id1:`AAA`BBB`CCC`DDD`EEE; id2:`02A`02B`02C`DD0`E25)

id1 id2
-------
AAA 02A
BBB 02B
CCC 02C
DDD DD0
EEE E25
```

---

My solution so far is to perform a left-join by changing the column `id2` to `id3` from `t2` and then apply the vector-conditional function `?`:

```
t1:t1 lj 1!select id1, id3:id2 from t2
t1[`id2]: ?[null t1[`id2];t1[`id3];t1[`id2]]
t1:delete id3 from t1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach using fill `^`:

```
q){key[x]#y^x}[1!t1;1!t2]
id1| id2
---| ---
AAA| 02A
BBB| 02B
CCC| 02C
DDD| DD0
EEE| E25
```

Comment: Thank you @terrylynch, this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

One liner below keys the table t2 then indexes into that table by passing it a table of the id1 column from t1 and selects the id2 value.
Then perform a fill(^) to only take this value where the id2 from t1 is null.

````
q)t1: ([] id1:`AAA`BBB`CCC`DDD`EEE; id2:```02C``E25)
q)t2: ([] id1:`AAA`BBB`CCC`DDD`SSS; id2:`02A`02B`C2C`DD0`SPE)
q)update (1!t2)[([]id1);`id2]^id2 from t1
id1 id2
-------
AAA 02A
BBB 02B
CCC 02C
DDD DD0
EEE E25
````

Answer (score 0):

You could simply filter out the rows from t2 for the symbols that are null in t1 and just do left join on this new table. This is also useful if your table has many columns to join.

```
q) t1 lj 1! select from t2 where id1 in exec id1 from t1 where id2=`
```